# Android Service which Run even after Killing the application

Tags: android, android-service, android-7.0-nougat, foreground-service, android-background

I am having Service using which we are getting the GPS Location by using callback method onLocation. And Android Service gets called every 3 seconds. Now I want to run the Service even if the App is cleared or killed from background.

In onStartCommand we are returning START_STICKY but the service onStartCommand is not getting called after clearing / killing of app.

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or real device? If it's a real device what is the model?

Comment: You cannot run permanent background services since android oreo even if you're trying to do tricks like autostart every x seconds.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing in real Mobile device and I have tested in multiple devices mentioned below but in none the service onStartCommand was invoked after app was cleared from background.

Lenovo k7 power Android 7.0
Xiaomi Redmi 8A Dual Android 10 ( here i enabled Auto Start from setting privacy )
Moto G6 ( Android 9.0 )............Pls find the source code below.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing in real Mobile device and I have tested in multiple devices mentioned below but in none the service onStartCommand was invoked after app was cleared from background.

1. Lenovo k7 power Android 7.0
2. Xiaomi Redmi 8A Dual Android 10 ( here i enabled Auto Start from setting privacy )
3. Moto G6 ( Android 9.0 )

Note : For Reference i have posted the service code that we are using. pls let me know why onStartCommand is not getting called after app was cleared from background.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GPSBackgroundService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    public static final String POLL_FREQUENCY = "frequency";
    public static final String INITIATED_BY = "initiatedBy";
    public static final String INITIATED_SCREEN = "initiated_screen";
    
    ServiceComponent serviceComponent;

    //public LocationManager locationManager;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    static Location previousPosition = null;
    double preLatitude, preLongitude;
    boolean haveLocationPermissionAccess = false, trackStoredLocally = false;
    String presentLat = "", presentLon = "";
    float totalDistTravelled = 0f;
    String dist_travelled = "0", previousDist = "", currentDate = "";
    int pollFrequency = 10000;
    String speed_calculated = "0.0";
    PreferencesHelper mPreferenceHelper;
    long preLongTime = 0L;
    //handler to update bunch of points in interval seq.
    Handler bulkLatLngThroughputManager;
    Runnable bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee;

    SimpleDateFormat mdformat;

    int notificationId = 5173;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = null;
    /*NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = null;*/
    Notification notification = null;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
    String dist = "0.0", text = "";
    int count = 0, countForTrackPoints = 0;

    static Location currentLocation;
    boolean allowForAnotherTrackCall= true;// =true for allowance and =false for dis allowance

    int success = 0,fail = 0,init = 0,dbs = 0,dbf = 0, rls=0;

    Intent requirementsOfListFragment,requirementsOfMapFragment;
    String initiatedBy = "";
    static String  initiatedScreen = "";
    String channelId = "",channelName = "";

    Double dist_temp = 0d;

    public static boolean allowNetworkCall = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onCreate called=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
        ConfigPersistentComponent configPersistentComponent = DaggerConfigPersistentComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(SuprabhatApplication.get(getApplicationContext()).getComponent())
                .build();
        serviceComponent = configPersistentComponent.serviceComponent(new ServiceModule(this));
        serviceComponent.inject(this);
        mPresenter.attachView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onStartCOMMAND called=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String channelId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? createNotificationChannel(notificationManager) : "";
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentText("Live tracking in progress...!")
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setChannelId(channelId)
                .build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(notificationId, notification);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onStartCOMMAND Leaving=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
        return  START_STICKY;
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private String createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
        channelId = "my_service_channelid";
        channelName = "My Foreground Service";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        // omitted the LED color
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        return channelId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i("onStart","onStart called");
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onStart called=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
        pollFrequency = intent.getIntExtra(POLL_FREQUENCY, pollFrequency);
        initiatedBy = intent.getStringExtra(INITIATED_BY);
        initiatedScreen = intent.getStringExtra(INITIATED_SCREEN);
        countForTrackPoints = mPresenter.getTrackLastCount();
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onStart FieldStaffTrans Count="+String.valueOf(countForTrackPoints), "abc.txt");
        // Create the Foreground Service
        currentDate = CommonUtils.getCurrentDate();
        bulkLatLngThroughputManager = new Handler();

        bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                sendTrackedPointsToRemoteLoc(initiatedScreen);
                allowForAnotherTrackCall = false;
                bulkLatLngThroughputManager.postDelayed(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee, pollFrequency);
            }
        };
        mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
          //  stopSelf();
            return;
        }
        haveLocationPermissionAccess = true;
        if (mPresenter != null) {
            totalDistTravelled = mPresenter.getTrackDistanceTravelled();
            writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onStart Started SHREDPREF totalDistTravelled="+String.valueOf(countForTrackPoints),"abcDistance.txt");
            dist_travelled = mPresenter.getTrackDistanceCalculated();
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        /*locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);*/
        bulkLatLngThroughputManager.postDelayed(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee, pollFrequency);

        requirementsOfListFragment = new Intent(CustomersInListFragment.GET_UPDATED_LOCATION_INFO);
        requirementsOfMapFragment = new Intent(CustomersOnMapFragment.GET_UPDATED_LOCATION_INFO);
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onStart after buildGoogleApiClient called=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000 / 2);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void sendTrackedPointsToRemoteLoc(String initiatedScreenLocal) {
        //Toast.makeText(SuprabhatApplication.getInstance(), "sendTrackedPointsToRemoteLoc called " + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInYYYYMMDDFormat(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        initiatedScreen = initiatedScreenLocal;
        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPointsToRemoteLoc called InitiatedScr=" + initiatedScreenLocal + " totalDistTravelled=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
        if (allowNetworkCall) {
            ArrayList<LatLngHolder> latLngHolderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<LatLngHolder> trackedPoints = mPresenter.getAllFSRTrackedRecords(currentDate);
            if (trackedPoints.size() > 0) {
                trackStoredLocally = true;
                latLngHolderArrayList.addAll(trackedPoints);
                rls = trackedPoints.size();
            }

            if (presentLat != null && presentLon != null && !presentLat.isEmpty() && !presentLon.isEmpty()) {
                if(countForTrackPoints > mPresenter.getTrackLastCount())
                    countForTrackPoints += 1;
                else {
                    countForTrackPoints = mPresenter.getTrackLastCount();
                    countForTrackPoints += 1;
                }
                //dist_temp += 100;
                LatLngHolder holder = new LatLngHolder(presentLat, presentLon, dist_travelled, speed_calculated, "", String.valueOf(countForTrackPoints), "Live");
                //LatLngHolder holder = new LatLngHolder(presentLat, presentLon, String.valueOf(dist_temp), speed_calculated, "", String.valueOf(countForTrackPoints), "Live");
                latLngHolderArrayList.add(holder);


                if (latLngHolderArrayList.size() > 1) {
                    mPresenter.sendTrackedPoints(latLngHolderArrayList, initiatedBy);
                } else if (latLngHolderArrayList.size() > 0) {
                    String strServerSentLattitude = mPresenter.getServerSentLattitude();
                    String strServerSentLongitude = mPresenter.getServerSentLongitude();
                    Double serverSentLatt,serverSentLong;
                    if (strServerSentLattitude ==null  || strServerSentLongitude == null) {

                        serverSentLatt = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                        serverSentLong = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                        mPresenter.setServerSentLattitude(String.valueOf(serverSentLatt));
                        mPresenter.setServerSentLongitude(String.valueOf(serverSentLong));
                        mPresenter.sendTrackedPoints(latLngHolderArrayList, initiatedBy);

                    } else {

                        serverSentLatt = Double.parseDouble(mPresenter.getServerSentLattitude());
                        serverSentLong = Double.parseDouble(mPresenter.getServerSentLongitude());


                        float[] results = new float[1];
                        Location.distanceBetween(
                                serverSentLatt, serverSentLong,
                                currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), results);
                        float difference = results[0];
                   /* mPresenter.sendTrackedPoints(latLngHolderArrayList,initiatedBy);
                   /* mPresenter.sendTrackedPoints(latLngHolderArrayList,initiatedBy);
                    previousLocation = currentLocation;*/
                        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPoints serverSentLatt="+serverSentLatt, "abc.txt");
                        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPoints serverSentLong="+serverSentLong, "abc.txt");
                        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPoints currentPosition.getLatitude()="+currentLocation.getLatitude(), "abc.txt");
                        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPoints currentPosition.getLongitude()="+currentLocation.getLongitude(), "abc.txt");
                        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPoints calulated distanceDiff=" + difference, "abc.txt");
                        if (difference >= 40) {//40

                            mPresenter.setServerSentLattitude(String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLatitude()));
                            mPresenter.setServerSentLongitude(String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude()));

                            writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " InitiatingToHitServer>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + difference, "abc.txt");
                            mPresenter.sendTrackedPoints(latLngHolderArrayList, initiatedBy);

                            //preLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                            //preLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                        } else {
                            writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " sendTrackedPointsToRemoteLoc distanceLesssThen40=" + initiatedScreenLocal + " totalDistTravelled=" + totalDistTravelled, "abc.txt");
                            countForTrackPoints -= 1;
                        }

                        //mPresenter.sendTrackedPoints(latLngHolderArrayList);
                    }
                }
            /*++init;
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: " + init + " s: " + success + " f: " + fail + " dbs: " + dbs+" dbf: "+dbf+" rls "+rls);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());*/
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    // n/w calls status illuminators
    @Override
    public void onSendingBulkTrackedPoints(FieldStaffPositionBackgroundPresenter.FieldNotesStartOrStopResultsCarrier resultsCarrier) {
        int tempTrackedPointsStrd = mPresenter.getTrackLastCount();
        if (tempTrackedPointsStrd < countForTrackPoints)
            mPresenter.storeTrackCurrentCount(countForTrackPoints);
        count++;
        if (trackStoredLocally) {
            //clear all local storage tracks
            mPresenter.deleteAllFsrStoredTracks();
            trackStoredLocally = false;
        }
        if (resultsCarrier.getStopLiveTracking().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            mPresenter.storeTrackDistanceCalculated("0");
            mPresenter.storeTrackDistanceTravelled(0f);
            bulkLatLngThroughputManager.removeCallbacks(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee);
         //   this.stopSelf();
        } else {

        }
        allowForAnotherTrackCall = true;
        /*++success;
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: "+init+" s: "+success+" f: "+fail+" dbs: "+dbs+" dbf: "+dbf+" rls "+rls);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrackPointsSendingError(String exception) {
        mPresenter.storeTrackCurrentCount(countForTrackPoints);
        mPresenter.storeFailedTrackInLocal(presentLat, presentLon, dist_travelled, speed_calculated, currentDate, mdformat.format(new Time(System.currentTimeMillis())), String.valueOf(countForTrackPoints));
        //bulkLatLngThroughputManager.postDelayed(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee,pollFrequency);
        allowForAnotherTrackCall = true;
        //FieldStaffPositionBackgroundTransmitter.writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onTrackPointsSendingError " + exception,"respnse.txt");
        /*++fail;
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: "+init+" s: "+success+" f: "+fail+" dbs: "+dbs+" dbf: "+dbf+" rls "+rls);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrackPointsSendingFailure(int statusCode, String message) {
        mPresenter.storeTrackCurrentCount(countForTrackPoints);
        mPresenter.storeFailedTrackInLocal(presentLat, presentLon, dist_travelled, speed_calculated, currentDate, mdformat.format(new Time(System.currentTimeMillis())), String.valueOf(countForTrackPoints));
        //bulkLatLngThroughputManager.postDelayed(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee,pollFrequency);
        allowForAnotherTrackCall = true;
        /*++fail;
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: "+init+" s: "+success+" f: "+fail+" dbs: "+dbs+" dbf: "+dbf+" rls "+rls);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());*/
        //FieldStaffPositionBackgroundTransmitter.writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " onTrackPointsSendingFailure " + message,"respnse.txt");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocalStorageOfTrackSuccess() {
        /*++dbs;
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: "+init+" s: "+success+" f: "+fail+" dbs: "+dbs+" dbf: "+dbf+" rls "+rls);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocalStorageOfTrackFailed(String exception) {
        /*++dbf;
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: "+init+" s: "+success+" f: "+fail+" dbs: "+dbs+" dbf: "+dbf+" rls "+rls);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());*/
    }

    public void writeDataToFile(String highestScore, String fileName) {
        try {
            //   if (mPresenter.getFFAEnableLogging().equals("Y")) {
            File data = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);
            File file = new File(data, fileName);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            bw.write(String.valueOf(highestScore));
            //bw.append(String.valueOf(highestScore));
            bw.close();
            //  }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //location related predefined helpers
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        
        if (location != null ) {
           
            currentLocation = location;
            

                requirementsOfListFragment.putExtra(CustomersInListFragment.PLOFS, presentLon);
                requirementsOfListFragment.putExtra(CustomersInListFragment.DCFS, dist_travelled);
                requirementsOfListFragment.putExtra(CustomersInListFragment.SCFS, speed_calculated);
                requirementsOfListFragment.putExtra(CustomersInListFragment.TDTFS,totalDistTravelled);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(requirementsOfListFragment);

                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.PLAFS, presentLat);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.PLOFS, presentLon);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.DCFS, dist_travelled);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.SCFS, speed_calculated);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.PLADFS,lat);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.PLODFS,lon);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.TDTFS,totalDistTravelled);
                requirementsOfMapFragment.putExtra(CustomersOnMapFragment.CLBR,location.getBearing());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(requirementsOfMapFragment);

                //++dbs;
                //notificationBuilder.setContentText("i: "+init+" s: "+success+" f: "+fail+" dbs: "+dbs);
                //notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            
        }
        
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        *//*Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);*//*
    }*/

    public void adamantForceCloseOfService()
    {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
        if (bulkLatLngThroughputManager != null && bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee != null) {
            bulkLatLngThroughputManager.removeCallbacks(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee);
        }
        /*if (locationManager!=null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }*/
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
        }
       // stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       /* writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " Service On onDestroyCalled", "abc.txt");
        if (bulkLatLngThroughputManager != null && bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee != null) {
            bulkLatLngThroughputManager.removeCallbacks(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee);
        }
        *//*if (locationManager!=null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }*//*
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelId);
            }
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
        stopSelf();
        super.onDestroy();*/
        //stopSelf();

        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " Service On onDestroyCalled", "abc.txt");
        Log.i("onDestroy","onDestroy Called");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, FieldStaffRestartBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        super.onDestroy();


    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        writeDataToFile("\n" + CommonUtils.getCurrentDateInDDMMYYYFormat() + " Service On onTaskRemoved called", "abc.txt");
        Log.i("EXIT", "onTaskRemoved!");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, FieldStaffRestartBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        //stoptimertask();
    }


   /* @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        if (bulkLatLngThroughputManager != null && bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee != null) {
            bulkLatLngThroughputManager.removeCallbacks(bulkLatLngThroughputEmployee);
        }
        *//*if (locationManager!=null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }*//*
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelId);
            }
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
        stopSelf();
        *//*try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*//*
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: My service is getting killed when the app is killed. Implemented Foreground service is, but its not working in Android 7.0 in other version its working. Pls let me know.